# Regex to match total number of interrupted characters

Tags: regex

I need to be able to detect when a string has 8 or more numbers, even when they are separated by periods - but that total 8 or more cannot include the periods. In other words, I can ignore periods when looking for a numeral string that includes 8 or more numbers.

I've tried countless combinations of capturing groups and non-capturing groups, regular sets and negated sets, and I just can't figure it out. But I've simplified my examples, below, to show the issue.

For example, the following regex will match, even though there are only 6 numbers total, but there are 8 total characters (obviously):

```
Expression:   [0-9\.]{8,}
Text:         12.34.56
```

Is there a regex expression that would allow me to ignore those periods?

Comment: Not sure about doing this with pure regex, so I'll skip to a workaround: can you do a string replacement first to remove all periods?

Comment: Its easy to detect with a regex if there is 8 or more numbers. What you can't do is not no-match the non-numbers - _if_ you want the numbers.

Comment: @mike.k For other circumstances I would definitely consider this option - but for this specific use-case, I can't alter the list of strings I'm checking. Thanks though!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This will validate a digit 8 or more times `^\D*(?:\d\D*){8,}$`
Basically, the single digit `\d` is surrounded by optional non-digits `\D`,
and matched in a group, 8 or more times.

Formatted:

```
 ^                   # Beginning of string
 \D*                 # 0 to many non-digits
 (?:                 # Cluster group
      \d                  # single digit
      \D*                 # 0 to many non-digits
 ){8,}               # 8 or more times
 $                   # End of string
```

Comment: Wow, thank you! I've only tested it out with a few minor examples, but it looks to be working perfectly. Seriously, I've been trying to finagle my noob regex knowledge for hours and hours. Thanks!